# How to calculate unknown parameters

Tags: fitting

I have measurement data from impact test-test specimen location (Charpy).
I am used by the plotting in excel this formula hyperbolical tan `Y=y0+a*tanh[(t-x0)/b]` from one scholarly article.

In the scholarly article they write, that “`y0, a, x0, b` calculated parameters for measurement data”. How, they do not write.

Parameters from item: `y0=126; a=115; x0=-33; b=25,5.`

`b`-is variable value at need

How I calculate this parameters `y0, a0, x0, b` for measurement data in *Mathematica*?

My curve in *Mathematica* is to same how in excel.

```
data = {{-70 , 10}, {-70, 15}, {-70, 20}, {-70, 43}, {-70, 48}, {-60, 20}, 
        {-60, 21}, {-60 , 23}, {-60, 48}, {-60 , 60}, {-60, 51}, {-50, 30}, 
        {-50, 38}, {-50, 49}, {-50, 75}, {-50, 90}, {-40, 50}, {-40, 55},
        {-40, 60}, {-40, 95}, {-40, 110}, {-40, 120}, {-40, 125}, {-40, 140},
        {-30, 98}, {-30, 125}, {-30, 145}, {-30, 155}, {-30, 160}, {-20, 149},
        {-20, 175}, {-20, 205}, {-20, 215}, {-20, 235}, {-10, 170}, {-10,172}, 
        {-10, 180}, {-10, 200}, {-10, 205}, {0, 200}, {0, 210}, {0,220}, 
        {0,225}, {0, 250}, {10, 210}, {10, 215}, {10, 235}, {10, 245},{10, 255}};

lm = LinearModelFit[data, {x^3, x^2, x}, x];

Show[ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> 450, PlotStyle -> Red], 
Plot[lm[x], {x, -70, 10}], Frame -> True]

(*lm["Properties"]*)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `NonlinearModelFit[]`?

Answer (score 6):

As J.M. suggests, NonlinearModelFit is your friend. Using the data you have and the starting values given:

```
curve = NonlinearModelFit[data, y0 + a*x0*Tanh[(t - x0)/b], 
              {{x0, -33}, {y0, 126}, {a, 115}, {b, 25.5}}, t]; 
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[curve[t], {t, -70, 10}]]
```

[image]

You can find the converged values of the fit by

```
curve
```

[image]

Comment: Thx Bill. Please do, how would you set constants(x0,y0,a,b) if I did not write them here?

Comment: These are initial guesses that the algorithm uses as a starting point. Most likely if you start "too far away" then you will be disappointed. In other words, you need to understand something about the structure of your function and let the algorithm fine tune the values.

Answer (score 0):

THX for precious directed to...

I modify for this:

```
curve = NonlinearModelFit[data, y0 + a*Tanh[(t - x0)/b],{a,b,x0,y0}, t]; 
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[curve[t], {t, -70, 10}]]
```

curve

[image]

```
FittedModel[123.929+106.55 Tanh[<<21>>(<<18>>+t)]]

curve["BestFitParameters"]
```

I had received:

```
{a -> 106.55, b -> 23.1277, x0 -> -33.4468, y0 -> 123.929}
```

|:Đ|